# How to add animation attribute in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

for example, I have xml file:

```
<set
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="100%"
android:pivotY="100%"

android:duration="1500"
android:startOffset="1500" />


<translate
android:fromXDelta="-50%p"
android:toXDelta="100%"
android:duration="2000"
 />
```

...
    

.

so, How can I do it dynamic, with my class .java?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [this blog](http://chandan-tech.blogspot.com/2011/01/world-of-animations-in-android.html). Just change "my_xml_file" to the name of your animation.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.my_xml_file);
myLayout.startAnimation(animation);
```